# problem in login in twitter from iphone

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4, twitter

I am using `MATwitterEngine` for implementing twitter in iphone app.
but at the time of login, i am having following error,

```
Fail: Error Domain=HTTP Code=401 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (HTTP error 401.)"
```

what could be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to use O-Auth for the login:

[bengottlieb / Twitter-OAuth-iPhone](https://github.com/bengottlieb/Twitter-OAuth-iPhone)

Unfortunately you have to implement O-Auth and can't simply manage your users' password and login yourself anymore. 
Twitter-Oauth-iPhone includes MGTwitterEngine